# Express body-parser req not shown

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using Express with body-parser as follows:

```js
// Import all required library

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '500mb'}))

var port = 3000


// Route for the API
var router = new express.Router()

router.get('/videos', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('GET /' + req)
    return res.json({
      "Your videos"
    })
})


// Using Router
app.use('/', router)


app.listen(port, function(err){
 if (!err) {
  console.log("API started running at port 3000")
 }
})
```

Versions of Library used are

```
    "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "1.16.1",
      "express": "4.14.1"
    }
```

This is not showing any query parameters in `req`. Resulting following

```
   GET /[object Object]
```

When I used POSTMAN to `GET` `localhost:3000/videos?type=popularity`.
This kind of api setup has been working for me until now. Can anyone explain me what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting in command prompt console?

Comment: Not any error rather I am not getting anything in req

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `console.log('GET /' + req)`, do:

```
console.log('GET /', req);
```

You'll get the full object.

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters are available through [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query):

```
console.log('GET /', req.query);
```

FWIW, `body-parser` is not a requirement to access these.

Comment: Thanks. only req.body is dependent on body-parser, right?